# Spa / Hot Tub power usage of a 220V circuit?

Tags: electrical, hot-tub

I have a 220V spa and would like to have an idea of how much power the spa is using. I have a power monitor and have swapped between both legs and get the exact same readings on both.
Here are the numbers the monitor provides:

> - 124 V (duh)
> - 17.34 Current A
> - 2.14 Power kW
> - 999 Energy kWh
> - 60 Freq. Hz (US)
> - 1.00 PF (Power Factor)

Is it simply using: 34.68 Amps / 4.28 kW / 1998 kWh ?

Comment: How long did you have the monitor connected? 999kWh would take 466 hours (19.5 days) to reach at 2.14kW constant draw. It’s also unlikely you read the meter exactly when it hit 999. Probably that’s an error, or your meter has memory, hit 999 after lots of use over time, and needs to be manually reset to 0.

Answer (score 3):

*At the moment of your reading* it is using 17.34A and 4.28kW.  You don't double the current.  The monitor is *assuming* the voltage is 120 and you have to double that to get the correct power.  There is probably a setting where you can do that.

The number of kWh depends on

1. The current/power over time ... presumably the load switches on and off and may vary at times.
2. How much time.  kWh per day, per month, per year?  Your above measurement, I'm guessing, is over some arbitrary period during which you took measurements.

Presumably 999 kWh is (half) the energy consumed during that period.   The *power consumption* during that period may not have *always* been 4.28kW.

The current is the same on both legs.  You don't need to measure both and you should not double it.  The Power is what you measure on one leg multiplied by 240V.  Your energy monitor should have a per-channel setting that lets you automatically double the power readings for 240V circuits measured this way, and it will automatically give you a correct total energy reading for whatever time period you choose.

In fact there are probably two settings:

1. The actual voltage setting.  If you have 124V per leg, there should be a setting for that.
2. A setting to say that a channel uses double the power ... that may be the "PF" setting, that you would set to 2.  Although, "power factor" usually means something else, but I wonder and suspect that in your device it means what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you jury-rigged something so that you are measuring half the circuit at a time.  This has resulted in half measures, literally.

The amperage is the same on each leg, because that is the actual amperage. Spa heaters don't use neutral so the current will be equal.

The spa is actually receiving 240V nominal, probably 248V in your case due to your somewhat high voltage.

The current is correct, so 17.34 amps.

The voltage monitor doesn't know the spa is "240V", so you must use the voltage you have x the current you know: 248V x 17.34A = 4300 VA. The PF of 1.00 makes sense given that it's a resistive load, so 4300 watts ***when the machine is running***.

It doesn't run continuously, so we need to know the *duty cycle* of the machine.  For that we need cumulated KWH, and the number of hours it took to cumulate that. Unfortunately, you do not have "hour" data, and the "kilowatt-hour" data is corrupted - 999 means it overflowed.  You would need to do another test. However, the monitor doesn't realize the voltage is twice what it can see, so you would need to take its KWH number and double it.

The KWH of the survey time, divided by the number of hours in the survey, gives *average* kilowatt draw.